# configuration of jmeter settings

Tags: jmeter

doesn anyone know what is the purpose of these settings 
httpclient.socket.http.cps
httpclient.socket.https.cps

from what I see it's to simulate slow connections but anyone has any example ?
for example to set 2s should I set the value = 2000 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cps` means `characters per second`.

- For example you have 1 megabyte response size and you want it to be downloaded not faster than in 2 seconds you need to throttle JMeter speed to `0.5` megabyte per second which gives you 512 kilobytes which is `524288` bytes (characters).

References:

- [Controlling Bandwidth in JMeter to simulate different networks](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/Controlling%20Bandwidth%20in%20JMeter%20to%20simulate%20different%20networks)
- [How to Simulate Different Network Speeds in Your JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-simulate-different-network-speeds-your-jmeter-load-test)